# Components are not rendering in quasar project with no error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I created Vue 3, quasar project. everything worked fine till the moment I add new component. everything is rendering except the new component which I built and added it to the project. please help me with this problem if you can.

Here is my code:
index page:

```js
<template>
  <q-page class="flex flex-center">
    <!-- section one-->
    <SectionOne />

  </q-page>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import SectionOne from "components/MainPage/SectionOne.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    SectionOne,
  },
  name: "IndexPage",
});
</script>
```

Component:

```js
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md q-gutter-md">
    <div class="row justify-between">
      <q-parallax src="https://cdn.quasar.dev/img/parallax2.jpg">
        <h1 class="text-white">Basic</h1>
      </q-parallax>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your project structure, but try this (missing "./")

```
import SectionOne from "./components/MainPage/SectionOne.vue";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also import from the root 'src' like this:

`import SectionOne from "src/components/MainPage/SectionOne.vue";`